# How to restrict two people log in with the same user credentials at any given time - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am researching on how to add protection to an existing rails app. The protection i need is to restrict two people log in with the same user credentials at any given time.

What would be the best approach around this?

I haven't seem to find any gem or something in particular.

Note that i am not using Devise but custom user authentication so please do not suggest anything related to devise.

Comment: A simple solution may be to store a user's session token as a column on your users table, refreshing the session token any time a login event occurs. This way, a fresh login from the same user account will end the previous session and log them out.

Comment: hmm thank you i might actually implement that!